# How to add a field to a report that has groups

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to add a field to a SSRS report.  I tried modifying the dataset (query) but the results prouduced insane results, with zipcodes showing up in the name fields and names showing up in a datetime field.  I suspect it is because of the groups but I don't understand how they work.  The Dataset is created by 4 selects.  The first 3 insert into temp tables and the fourth pulls from it.  I suspect that I will have to re-write the query but it would be nice if I could use it as is with modifications.  Either way I need to understand the groups.

I read
[Data Region Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220511.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [Data Region](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220587.aspx) and [Understanding Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255263.aspx).  Aside from the fact that they use terms specific to SSRS without defining them they are so undetailed I doubt many people who do not already understand SSRS can get anything out of them.

I did not write this report but I must modify it.  I understand SQL well.  Not so much with SSRS.

Can anyone explain how to find out what the Row Groups mean?  Mine look like this:
[image: Row Groups]

Here is the tablix
[image: tablix]

Comment: `Row Groups` in SSRS works in a similar way to `GROUP BY` clause in SQL, the SQL translation should be `Group by ClientID, Table1_ClientID, Table1_name, table1_OfficePhone, table1_AccessionId`. Each field in a tablix is in a specific scope determined by the cell where you place it. A tablix image could be useful.

Comment: In SSRS, you can add fields to a ROW without adding them as a new ROW GROUP. If your `NAME` field is for the `CLIENT_ID` ( 1 to 1 relationship), then you wouldn't need to GROUP on both. For instance, you wouldn't need to group on `OfficePhone` if there is only one phone number per `Client_ID`. You only need to use a new group when you want to aggregate multiple rows of data.

Comment: @alejandro, thanks for your reply.  I added the tablix.  One thing I don't understand is why is Client ID listed twice.  It is only in the dataset once.  What is the table1 prefix mean?  Do I just ignore the first row (ClientID) and last one (table1_Details_Group)?  When I run the SQL in management studio and add GROUP BY ClientID, name, OfficePhone,  Accession I get less rows than the report gets.

Comment: @Hannover, You were correct, I was able to delete the name and office phone groups and it didn't affect the page count so I will presume they are not needed.